# App Crash in App Store but works in TestFlight

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, app-store, testflight

I have submitted recently (like 5 h ago) a Xamarin.IOS app to AppStore, but it is crashing right after the user logs in. We performed tests on simulators, devices and through Test Flight. It works well in all scenarios except when the user downloads the app from AppStore.
We tried so far:
    1. check the crash logs

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4296392704
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 000000010015c000-0000000100420000 [ 2832K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  .../MyAwesomeAppName.iOS

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  tid_407  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b20d2d88 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001b1fef74c pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b1f3e9b0 __abort + 112
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b1f3e940 __abort + 0
4   MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x00000001037211fc xamarin_localized_string_format_9 + 15196
5   MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x0000000103715fb8 xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 7812
6   MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x00000001035db9c4 gc.safepoint_poll + 52123060
7   MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x00000001035709fc gc.safepoint_poll + 51684844
8   MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x00000001035713f0 gc.safepoint_poll + 51687392
9   MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x000000010356531c gc.safepoint_poll + 51638028
10  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x000000010053cd38 gc.safepoint_poll + 1141032
11  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x00000001015d5b58 gc.safepoint_poll + 18544456
12  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x0000000100426a40 gc.safepoint_poll + 1584
13  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x0000000100512480 gc.safepoint_poll + 966768
14  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x00000001035825fc gc.safepoint_poll + 51757548
15  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x000000010363dad8 gc.safepoint_poll + 52524744
16  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x0000000103643d30 gc.safepoint_poll + 52549920
17  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x0000000103560bb4 gc.safepoint_poll + 51619748
18  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x000000010371dc30 xamarin_localized_string_format_9 + 1424
19  MyAwesomeAppName.iOS                    0x0000000100423aac GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth + 993268
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001b20dd8f0 start + 4
```

2. To try to reproduce it in a debug environment: Without success

We are out of ideas and it would be great if somebody could lead us in the right direction to answer the following questions:
1. Why the app is not working only if the user downloads from AppStore and it works when downloaded from TestFlight?
2. How to decipher the crash log correctly to understand it better? We tried to symbolisticate it but the output looks pretty much the same as the initial crashlog.

Comment: 1. It maybe caused my some old data or setting in the old app which not work with the app of new version. 2. The crash log you post does not help much and the only thing I get is the crash maybe caused by the GoogleMobileAds.

Answer (score 1):

I just leave our solution here, maybe somebody will end up in the same dilemma:
Since the crashlogs were not pointing us to a certain location we started to think about the differences between Testflight and AppStore. The single major difference we found was the in-app purchases. So after a short investigation in the code we found out that if the in-app purchases are unavailable in the appstore we end up with a null pointer which causes an exception, handling correctly this scenario solved the problem since our in-app purchases were lagging in the AppStoreConnect review process.
If you end up in the same paradox you might want to check:
1. if you have bitcode enabled
2. if you are handling well in-app purchases
3. if you have external API which might behave differently in Testflight and Appstore scenarios.